A good movie that featured a row of toilets that the seats flipped up on command
Military movie in Black and white with mechanical devices for toilets was a hit sometime in the 50's

Could you edit to add what sci-fi or fantasy elements it might have contained?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about a science fiction or fantasy work. But if you are looking to identify an on-topic work, please [edit] your question and share more details about its sci-fi or fantasy aspects so that we can better help you. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

I believe it is the movie "No Time for Sargeants" the Toilet salute.



However, I agree there is no sci-fi or fantasy element to it.
